# SQl Script file need to execute in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I had .sql file in D:/xxx/User.sql file, and mysql home in c drive. Now i want to import this .sql file in Pr Schema  Till now what i tried is `msql -u root -p<d:/xxx/User.sql file` . I am trying to dump in this way by following one on link. can any 1 please let me know the exact procedure for executing sql file in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
msql -u root -p<d:/xxx/User.sql file
```

Well, this has several mistakes.

The command is `mysql` not `msql`.

There needs to be a whitespace between `-p` and `<d:/xxx/User.sql file`

What is the `file` at the end of this command? This shouldn't be there.

Note, there should only not be a whitespace after -p when you actually specify a password.

You haven't specified a database, in which your script should be running.

The correct way should be

```
mysql -u root -p yourDatabaseName < d:/xxx/User.sql
```

Flo Doe's answer is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to you mysql instance and select the schema where you want to execute this file. The use the following command:

```
source d:/xxx/User.sql;
```

See also [mysql docs - batch commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can import .sql file by phpmyadmin then to database in which you have to import then on Right side upper an column name import is there select exact position and import it

Comment: cant i import .sql file directly from mysql database,

Comment: $ mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql this syntax can do this